# Updated Android Studio to 0.5.3 gradle error

Tags: android, gradle

I updated my Android Studio to 0.5.3 version and showed Gradle error

```
12:59:40 Gradle 'ShareMe' project refresh failed:
         A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
         : Gradle settings
```

Does anyone knows what the problem is and how to fix it?
It was working on 0.5.2

**EDIT**
After gradlew --stacktrace

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX>gradlew --stacktrace
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been depre
cated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2 is ignored for de
faultFlavorDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by
Android.
In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class
packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2 is ignored for de
faultFlavorRelease as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided b
 y Android.
    In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class
 packages
:help
```

Comment: why the hell on earth downvote??

Comment: Try to use this command from command line: gradlew --stacktrace. The gradlew file is in your project's folder. It will print all the exceptions, maybe it will be more informative.

Comment: @coelho, thanks i updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Restarting** the computer fixed the problem.

It is strange.